# Kinect v2 demos not working?

Tags: wpf, kinect-sdk, kinect-v2

Probably missed something- been a while since I cracked these apps open with the v2 kinect.  I'm just trying to run the BodyIndexBasics-WPF application freshly installed from the kinect studio demo and while it compiles fine it crashes with the following error:

`'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.BodyIndexBasics.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.`

This only seems to happen for the WPF apps (C++ stuff is fine), and if I create a native WPF application from scratch it also works fine.  But when I add in code from the SDK it creates this error.

I'm using SDK v2.0_1409 on a windows 10 pro box with v 14971.rs_prerelease.161111-1700.

Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Comment: Hi Nicros. I'm pretty sure the issue is with using windows 10... Are you able to replicate this in windows 8? I'm pretty sure that's the problem

Comment: No windows 8 box to test with. But if I comment out everything in the code-behind, the app runs.  If I add in this one line:

private BodyIndexFrameReader bodyIndexFrameReader = null; 

OUTSIDE the constructor, it blows up.  If I that same line (minus the private) inside the constructor then it works.

Comment: very strange behaviour... try to report it in the official SDK page from Kinect.

Comment: Definitely the issue is with your OS. I just tried running BodyIndexWPF on mine and it worked right away. My specs are: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0. 

Project was compiled in Debug mode for AnyCPU.